# Return `void` from `async` funtion

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I ran into this a few times now and I've always just ignored it.

In TypeScript when I code:

```js
async function someAsyncFunc(): void {
    const prom = await somePromise();
}
```

It complains to me that async function should always have the return type of: `Promise<T>`. So what it wants from me is:

```
async function someAsyncFunc(): Promise<void>
```

I know that, but this method does not return **anything**. Up to this point, I've just always given in, and used the type `Promise<void>` but this will lead to bugs as TypeScript now thinks this function returns a promise, won't it?

Had an idea whilst writing this question and tested it.. turned out to be true. Check out my own answer in case your wondering :)

Error message so it will hopefully be index by google:

```
The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type.
```

Comment: It does return a promise. All async functions return a promise. The promise might wrap a return value. Otherwise (for a void returning async functions), the promise wraps nothing.  It's a good thing that typescript thinks that it's a function that returns a promise, because that's exactly what it is.

Comment: @spender Yes, I know that it is a promise internally. But I didn't know at this point that any `async` function implicitly returns one.

Answer (score 3):

An async function is consider an extension of the [Promise paradigm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

For javascript/typescript know that the return of a specific **function** **is asynchronous is because it return a Promise**. This means that **the return type** of an **ansynchronous function** **is always** **Promise**. Then, you can wrap a value into that promise which can be *void*, *number*, *string*, another *promise*, etc.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> **An asynchronous function** is a function which operates asynchronously
>   via the event loop, **using an implicit Promise to return its result**.

More over:

> An async function can contain an await expression that pauses the
>   execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's
>   resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and
>   returns the resolved value. Remember, the await keyword is only valid
>   inside async functions.

***Resuming: The aysnc/await in functions are syntax sugar to facilitate the code readability.***

Comment: Wasn't that exactly what I wrote in my answer?

Comment: But this is a better answer than mine because it provides references to the MDN :)

Answer (score 0):

Whist writing this question the solution came to my mind. So now I'm answering this myself in case anyone else is wondering.

When you create an `async function` JavaScript implicitly returns a Promise (which then will be void). Much like if you're writing a normal void function you don't have to put `return;` at the end, it just does return.

```js
async function test() {};
// Will return a resolved void promise
// the code snipped result only shows "{}" check it out in
// the browser console and you'll see
console.log(test());
```

Answer (score 0):

Async functions will always return a promise. The result of your answer to your question should print `Promise{<state>: "<finished>"}` instead of void. You need to await the async function to see the `void` response

```
async function test() {};
console.log(test());
```

becomes

```
async function test() {};
console.log(await test());
```

Comment: Wasn't that exactly what I wrote in my answer?

Comment: What I meant by void is that it does not return anything, not that it explicitly says void.

Comment: @Elias It is almost exactly like your answer, but the difference is awaiting on test() vs not awaiting on test()